# Edit option blocked

Tags: support, privileges, edits

My edit privilege is blocked and I cannot edit any question or answer. I had that option working a few hours ago. My reputation now is 441. Is there a reason for the privilege to be blocked?
Maybe my edit quality is too low?

Comment: "Aswin Murugesh had 8 edit suggestions approved, and 6 edit suggestions rejected" (that is why, your ratio is too low. It's probably a 1 week ban). See http://stackoverflow.com/users/2046858/aswin-murugesh?tab=activity witht the filter suggestions to see your edit suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at a few of your recent suggested edits, in the 7 most recent suggested edits, you have 5 edits rejected (3 of them are rejected normally with reviewer's vote):

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1935978

  Why do you change the code in the question? As a reviewer, I can't see this as anything but a major change to the post.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1934472
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1934427

  It seems that you are editing the question to try to fix some problem in their code. **Please do NOT do so**. The problem in their code might be the reason why they are asking the question in the first place. Changing the code in the question may invalidate all the existing answer, or make the rest of the question irrelevant.

  The only case such change is valid is when the author of the question clarifies in some comment about their requirement. Please link to the comment in such case for reviewer's reference.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1925425

  It might be the case that you are rejected (by reviewer editing), since the indentation is off for the last line of first block of code. This is quite a borderline case, in my opinion.
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1916666

  This is most probably due to race condition of your suggested edit and [tacp's edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15991965/revisions), since they are made at around the same time, and tacp's edit is more thorough than yours.